# Problem with card image load in Electron ReactJS and Material-Ui

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, electron

How to load a local image?? I use Electron Reactjs and Material-UI package.

My code here:

```
         <CardMedia
            className={classes.media}
            image="../../../assets/img/keylime-pie.jpeg"
            title="Contemplative Reptile"
          />
```

And the error was:

GET file:///static/images/cards/live-from-space.jpg net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND

Please help to solve this problem, Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

Unless the images are in public folder you'll have to import before using them.

```
import CardMediaImage from '../Assets/img/keylime-pie.jpeg';

<CardMedia
  className={classes.media}
  image={CardMediaImage}
  title="Contemplative Reptile"
/>
```

Update:

I believe your `CardMedia` expects the path to image. In such case you can move your images inside public folder for eg.,
`public/Assets/img/keylime-pie-jpeg`, and then you can provide the path without `public` in it.

```
<CardMedia
  className={classes.media}
  image='/Assets/img/keylime-pie.jpeg'
  title="Contemplative Reptile"
/>
```

Comment: Showing this error; Uncaught Error: Module parse failed: Unexpected character '�' (1:0)

Comment: How are you using the `image` prop in your `CardMedia` component? Can you show `CardMedia`'s image implemenation code?

Comment: Card Media's Code:

   <CardMedia
            className={classes.media}
            image={CardMediaImage}
            title="Contemplative Reptile"
          />

Comment: I meant the CardMedia component's code and not how you're invoking it. You can edit your question and add it to it, instead of putting in comments.

Comment: See my question now

Comment: Not asking for the error, asking for the source code for the `CardMedia` component, how you've written it

Comment: copy from Material UI

Comment: When I add the HTTPS image path works fine. but   add the local image  thrown error